# Documentation to the Google Calendar API php client library

Tags: php, api, documentation, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I want to use the Google Calendar API php client library, it seems to work for the [basic example available](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/calendar/simple.php) but I can't find any documentation/class-list/methods/api-explanation anywhere.

Are there anything available at all or do I have to dig the source file?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Google has not yet released proper documentation for any of their Calendar API v3 client libraries.

Comment: And I'm kind of frustrated about that...

Comment: And I really don't blame you. I've been working on building my own library in VBA since they don't even put one out. You might be best off rolling your own too. If you can work with JSON it's not all that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps API client: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/setup

Calendar V3 API documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/

Examples: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents

Is that what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Google's documentation seems to be outdated...

For the best chance you should head over to http://amazewebs.com

AmazeWebs has more than enough information to help you understand and write your own Google API Calendar Scripts. Using PHP and following the demonstration videos; you can have a script 'up and running' in minutes! ...including example scripts, instructional videos, PDF help guides (common debugging), 1-to-1 support etc...

See the demo of a simple script: http://amazewebs.com/demo

Download a working copy of the API Client Library v3 here: http://amazewebs.com/downloads/google-api.zip

See the demo in action here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6aurr7TDMI